# Using ApplicationDbContext in ASP.Net Core Web App Framework .NET 6.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm new to Entity Framework. I created a site that uses Microsoft Identity which created the `ApplicationDbContext.cs` file.

Now I'm trying to add my own entity named `Setting`. I added a migration which created a `Settings` table in the database.

I'm not sure how or where to add the new `Settings` `DbSet` or if this is handled automatically when I added the migration.

The new table is in the migration, but not in the snapshot. Do I need to create a separate context/where to go from here?

Here's the `ApplicationDbContext` created when I installed Identity:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EF Core usually operates with entities exposed as `DbSet`'s. `IdentityDbContext` [has some already predefined](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore/IdentityDbContext.cs,77). If you need to add a new table you can just add the corresponding `DbSet` and create a migration (delete the one you previously have created):

```cs
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Setting> Settings { get; set; }
}
```

Check out the [EF Core docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/overview/first-app?tabs=netcore-cli), especially:

- [Entity Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/entity-types?tabs=data-annotations)
- [Managing Database Schemas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/)

Comment: Shouldn't that be `public virtual DbSet<Setting> Settings { get; set; }` ?? Just like the pre-defined dbsets of the Identity subsystem?

Comment: Thanks, deleting the migration, adding the dbset and then adding the migration back fixed the issue.